# Oracle's SQL to extract values between two chars in a list

Tags: sql, regex, oracle

I have a list of value such as:

```
'aaa:data1!x,bbb:data2!y,cc:data3!z'
```

I need to extract values between ':' and '!' such as `data1 data2 data3`

I tried this:

```
SELECT regexp_substr('aaa:data1!x,bbb:data2!y,cc:data3!z', 
                     '\:([^!]+)\!', 
                     1,
                     1,
                     NULL,
                     1) AS output
FROM dual;
```

But it returns me only `data1`

Comment: Do the list strings always have exactly three data components?

Comment: @Ork . . . Do you want separate rows or a string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're on the right way, just need to send an iterated integers to the 4th argument of `regexp_substr` function

This gives vertical result :

```
with t(str) as
(
 select 'aaa:data1!x,bbb:data2!y,cc:data3!z' from dual
) 
select regexp_substr(str,
                     ':([^!]+)',
                     1,
                     level,
                     null,
                     1) as output                     
  from t
 connect by level <= regexp_count(str,'!');

 OUTPUT
 ------
 data1
 data2
 data3
```

This gives horizontal result :

```
with t(str) as
(
 select 'aaa:data1!x,bbb:data2!y,cc:data3!z' from dual
), t2 as
( 
 select regexp_substr(str,
                     ':([^!]+)',
                     1,
                     level,
                     null,
                     1) as output                     
   from t
 connect by level <= regexp_count(str,'!') 
)
select listagg(output,' ') within group (order by output) as output from t2  

 OUTPUT
 -----------------
 data1 data2 data3
```

Comment: Barbaros, my dear friend, why do you specify "\" before ":" and "!" ?

Comment: @akk0rd87 yes no need, thank you :) didn't consider much about after getting the main trick.

Comment: @akk0rd87 moreover, even using `!` once is enough(  `':([^!]+)'` instead of `':([^!]+)!'`  ) .

Comment: Add colon ':[^:!]+!'

Comment: @akk0rd87 but `':[^:!]+!'` pattern gives null as output.

Answer (score 1):

Good, old `SUBSTR` + `INSTR` does the job:

```
SQL> with test (col) as
  2    (select 'aaa:data1!x,bbb:data2!y,cc:data3!z' from dual)
  3  select substr(col, instr(col, ':', 1, level) + 1,
  4                     instr(col, '!', 1, level) - instr(col, ':', 1, level) - 1
  5               ) result
  6  from test
  7  connect by level <= regexp_count(col, ':');

RESULT
----------------------------------
data1
data2
data3

SQL>
```